# ExtJS 4 recaptcha form

Tags: extjs4, recaptcha

I have set up a key and can get the recaptcha to show on the page it self but I don't know how to get it into a form.

Actually I don't want to use an id since I'll be reusing this later inside the app too so to use itemId would be preferred.I'm assuming that the element hasn't been created yet.

My include:
HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Error (generated from recaptcha_ajax.js. Can't get the control with id 'recaptcha'):
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Here's the code:

```
Ext.define('Login.view.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.Login.view.Login',


border: false,
bodyPadding: 5,


initComponent: function() {


    var config = {
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%',
            allowBlank: false
        },
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Company Id',
            name: 'companyId'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Username',
            name: 'username'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Password',
            name: 'password',
            inputType: 'password'
        },{
            /*xtype: 'panel',
            itemId: 'reCaptcha',
            border: false,*/
            html: '<div id="recaptcha">adsf</div>'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Login'
        }]
    };
    Ext.apply(this, config);


    this.callParent();
},
afterRender: function() {
    Recaptcha.create("heres_my_public_key",
        document.getElementById('recaptcha'),
        {
            theme: "clean"/*,
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field*/
        }
    );
    this.callParent();
}
});
```

Anyone done this using ExtJS 4?

/K

Comment: please do not use just external links in your posts. If they break the whole post is worthless...

Comment: noted. actually pretty funny. sencha went down today... and is still down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

captcha created too early. Solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-4.0.6/resources/css/ext-all.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../Icon.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4.0.6/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

Ext.define('Login.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Login.view.Login',

    border: false,
    bodyPadding: 5,

    initComponent: function() {

        var config = {
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                allowBlank: false
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'Company Id',
                name: 'companyId'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                name: 'username'
            },{
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'password',
                inputType: 'password'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                itemId: 'reCaptcha',
                border: false,
                html: '<div id="recaptcha">adsf</div>',
                listeners:{
                     {
                        console.log(Ext.getDom(this.body));
                        Recaptcha.create("heres_my_public_key",
                            Ext.getDom(this.body),
                            {
                                theme: "clean",
                                callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Login'
            }]
        };


        Ext.apply(this, config);

        this.callParent();
    }/*,
    afterRender: function() {
        var captchaEl = Ext.get('recaptcha');
        console.log(captchaEl);
        Recaptcha.create("heres_my_public_key",
            document.getElementById('recaptcha'),
            {
                theme: "clean",
                callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
            }
        );
        this.callParent();
    }*/
});

// entry point
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var l = Ext.create('Login.view.Login', {renderTo:Ext.getBody()});
}); // eo onReady

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

//after creating reCaptcha div call the following lines.

< div id="reCaptcha" > < / div>

if ($("#reCaptcha").length>0)

```
        showRecaptcha("reCaptcha");
```

function showRecaptcha(element) {

```
$.getScript('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js',
    function () {
        Recaptcha.create("your public key", element, {
            theme: "red",
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
    });
```

}