# Need captcha field in registration form using ExtJS

Tags: extjs, captcha, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS 4.2 and I am not able to get the captcha field in my registration form. Can
anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: extjs has no captcha field where do you get it from?

Comment: I need captcha in my form, Is there any way to integrate java captcha with ExtJs

Comment: then add information about this captcha framework to your question and add a tag for the framework if there is any. so the people with the right knowledge can find your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779712/extjs-4-recaptcha-form might help

Comment: @KyleFransham thank you for your help but i cannot get the captcha in that how can i get the public key and how can i use.

Answer (score 0):

I use google recpatcha.  I'll paste my client side code below here. you'll need to do the server side yourself.  you need to include the google recaptcha library and have a panel on your form like what is below.  then, when you submit, the google values to up and need to be verified.

ExtJS:

```
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                border: false,
                height: 150,
                html: '<div id="recaptcha">Captcha Control From Google. This should be replaced by image by google</div>',
                itemId: 'reCaptcha',
                margin: '0 0 0 105'
            }
```

JavaScript Submit Click Event

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Creating New Account..."});
myMask.show();

localValues.recaptchaChallengeField = Recaptcha.get_challenge();
localValues.recaptchaResponseField =Recaptcha.get_response();

Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response, options) {
myMask.hide();
if (response.status != 200) {
    var errorData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);


    Ext.MessageBox.show({
        title: 'Error Message',
        msg: errorData.message,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
    });
    Ext.Msg.alert('Creating User Failed',errorData.message);
}
});

Ext.Ajax.request({
url:'/rpc/Account/CreateUser',
actionMethods:'POST',
scope:this,
params: localValues,
success: function(r, o) {
    myMask.hide();
    var retData = Ext.JSON.decode(r.responseText);


    } else {
        tabPanel.setActiveTab(tabPanel.getTabIdByName('AttendeeAfterLoginConf'));
    }

},
failure: function(r,o) {
     myMask.hide();
    // handled in exception now
    //debugger;
    //Ext.Msg.alert('Creating User Failed','');
}
});
```